# C: Malloc String Array Confusion

Tags: c, arrays, string, cygwin, malloc

I'm attempting to allocate sufficient space to hold all command line arguments given to an array `arg_list` in reverse order.

```
char* arg_list[6];
arg_list = malloc((sizeof(char*)) * argc);
for (i=argc; i < 0; i--)
{
    arg_list[i]=argv[i];  
}
```

My theory was on `malloc` to get the `sizeof` a `char*` and then multiply that by how many arguments that were given, `argc` giving the total amount of space needed.

Then using the for loop, start `i` at the number of elements, `argc`, say 5 for example, and then put the 5th element of `argv` into the 5th spot in `arg_list` and do this until it gets to 0.

I'm getting warnings of `incompatible implicit declaration` and an error of `assignment to expression with array type` and am not sure where I'm going wrong. Also, I've been using C for about a day and a half now, so dumb everything down as much as possible if you could! I'd really appreciate it!

EDIT: Trouble Printing out the Reversed array
Code:

```
    char** arg_list = malloc((sizeof(char*)) * argc);

/** arg_list points to the command-line arguments in the */
/**     reversed order */
for (i=argc-1; i >= 0; i -=1)
{
    arg_list[i]=argv[i];  
}

/** print the content of arg_list */
/** fill here */
for (i=0; i<argc; i++)
{
    printf(arg_list[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

I am confused on how I would go about printing the reversed order. Whenever I print it, it prints in the normal order and not reverse. I am confused on how it gets put in `arg_list` in the normal order instead of the reverse. Thanks!

Comment: Shoudn't your loop be `for (i = argc - 1; i > 0; i--)`, since you are counting down?

Comment: What would that be useful for, as you already have that data available?

Comment: @Olaf I want to reverse the order of `argv` in `arg_list`. It's just a learning exercise

Comment: `arg_list` is not an array! A pointer is not an array and vice-versa.

Comment: @Olaf I am so confused... whatever I am doing is filling `arg_list` and when I try to print `arg_list` out, it prints, but it prints in the normal order, not the reverse order. Any suggestions?

Comment: I rolled back the question. You must not change a question making an existing answer useless! You might, however, add the new information, but  be careful not to change the question as such (e.g. add an extra section at the end). This is not a nastiness, but site rules. Please take the [tour] and see [ask]. (Note your edit is still in the revision history, nothing is lost)

Comment: @Olaf I have edited my question and have added my issue and was wondering if you could take the time to take a look at it. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. There are declarations missing. And format the code properly. Also note that you always should use a format string for `printf`. As you output externally supplied data, this is actually **vital**, as your code widely opens a security hole - just think what happens iof you print something like `%s`! Does the edited version still not work?

Comment: @Olaf the version posted is still not printing in reverse order and I am completely lost as to why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering on the edited version which already includes the corrections from the other answers and comments.

Lean back and have a look at

```
for ...
    arg_list[i] = argv[i];
```

So, you assign the pointer at position `[i]` to the pointer at position `[i]`:

```
arg_list[argc-1] = argv[argc-1];
...
arg_list[1] = argv[1];
arg_list[0] = argv[0];
```

Now think what *reverse* means ...

Try to follow me. Drop a comment if you are done (either successful or not) and I'll provide the full solution. But please try yourself first, it really is very simple and it will help you much more than a fully presented solution.

---

Resolution: You have to index both arrays from different directions:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < argc ; i++ )
    arg_list[i] = argv[ argc - 1 - i];
```

I changed to loop to the more obvious incrementing loop,a s the direction does not matter.

Note that the index of the uppermost entry is `argc - 1`, not `argc`, as in C - as in most programming languages - indexes run from 0.

---

**Warning:** When printing variable data you **always** should use a format-string for `printf` & family. This becomes mandatory when prionting externally supplied data like the command-line arguments. Failing to do widely opens a security hole. Just think about supplying `%s` as argument. That effectively results in:

```
printf("%s");
```

Note that you do not supply the required string argument, but `printf` tries to read it.

Comment: I appreciate all your help!

Comment: @Bob: Welcome. Good you saw it yourself. Keep that in mind for your next problem: try to run the code in your head when you have a problem. Or in a debugger. I added the solution to complete my answer (not sure I should, but I think it is better for completeness). Note you are off by one (which is a very typical error) in your comment! Don't hesitate to use your fingers or whatever helps you to track indexes, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have declared

```
char* arg_list[6];
```

you cannot assign anything to `arg_list`. You can only assign to its elements. Hence,

```
arg_list = malloc(...);
```

is wrong. You can use:

```
arg_list[0] = malloc(...);
```

but that's not what you are after.

You need to use:

```
char** arg_list = malloc((sizeof(char*)) * argc);
```

Comment: It's still giving warnings of `implicit declaration of function` and `incompatible implicit declaration` and `iso c90 forbids mixed declarations and code`. I'm not so much worried about all that since it compiles, but when I try to print it out with `for` loop using `printf(arg_list[i]); it comes up with `X60`?

Comment: Yes, that's his first problem. After that, the loop has two mistakes: it should be `for (i = argc -1; i >= 0; i -= 1)`. Finally, since you're just copying the pointers from `argv` and not copying the strings themselves, I see no reason for this code to exist: anything you can do with `arg_list` you can just do with `argv`. I don't see any functions here, so I can't explain the errors: show us all the code.

Comment: @Bob, your comment here underscores the importance of a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please post one.

Comment: I have figured out my issue with print it, but for whatever reason it's not saving `argv` in reverse order in `arg_list`

Answer (score 1):

You want `char **arg_list;`

Also, for `argc` items, the maximum subscript is `[argc - 1],` so you will want to adjust that loop.